# Insert std::unique_ptr into boost:ptr_map

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14

I'm moving some old code to c++14, it used the deprecated auto_ptr and that worked well with boost:ptr_map, you could do:

```
auto_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo);
boost:map_ptr<int, Foo> m;
m.insert(5, foo);
```

Now, replacing that auto_ptr with unique_ptr, it doesn't compile:

```
unique_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo);
boost:map_ptr<int, Foo> m;
m.insert(5, foo);            // Does not compile
m.insert(5, move(foo));      // Does not compile either,
                             // this should be the right thing to do
m.insert(5, move.release()); // Does compile, but isn't exception safe
```

Is map_ptr API just not up to date yet?

Edit based on responses, using map of unique_ptr is not a good option in my case because it requires rewrite of a fair amount of code. I really wanted to make it work with map_ptr, I'm dealing with some old code and I wish to make minimum changes.

Comment: What is boost ptr_map? Are you sure you still need that in C++14? I don't think you do, those old pointer containers were to address the fact that auto_ptr couldn't actually be generically handled by containers.

Comment: Why not just use a `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`?

Answer (score 3):

I think in C++14 what you want is this:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> x;
x.emplace(5, std::make_unique<Foo>());
```

You don't need those old boost _ptr containers any more, they were basically workarounds for the lack of an owning, zero overhead pointer that could safely be handled in containers (i.e. `unique_ptr`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> x;
x.emplace(5, std::make_unique<Foo>());
```

Its a C++14 feature. No need for the old boost containers!!! :)

Comment: Good point, I should have mentioned this wasn't an option for me since that is not a drop-in replacement for ptr_map like unique_ptr mostly was for auto_ptr for the particular code I have in had. And I have to say that ptr_map is a little bit nicer to use compared to a map of unique_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

> Is map_ptr API just not up to date yet?

No, you're just using it the wrong way.

As from the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_map.html):

> A ptr_map is a pointer container that uses an underlying std::map to store the pointers.

Note that this doesn't compile:

```
unique_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo);
void *ptr = foo;
```

Because you cannot convert a `std::unique_ptr` to `void *` with an assignment, it doesn't make much sense.
That's more or less what happens internally when you try to do with this:

```
m.insert(5, move(foo));
```

On the other side this compiles instead:

```
unique_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo);
Foo *bar = foo.realease();
void *ptr = bar;
```

That's something close to:

```
m.insert(5, move.release());
```

Therefore you cannot expect the first case to work and actually it doesn't.

---

That being said, nowadays I'd rather use a map of int and `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` from the standard template library and get rid of `boost::ptr_map`, as suggested in the comments to the question.
Something like the following should work:

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>
```

Note that a `std::map` is more appropriate than a `std::unordered_map` if you want something closer to how `boost::ptr_map` works for, as mentioned above, its underlying data structure is an `std::map` and not an `std::unordered_map`.